# One folder is missing in git and pushed as a file

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have tried many things to push my project from intellij to Bitbucket. I have to insert two screenshots to explain what is the problem: everything is pushed fine, but the folder "frontend" is pushed as a file.
[image]

[image]

I did force push, and tried to delete the repo and retry, but nothing works. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think it's pushed as a `file` but rather there's a conflict with that folder. The ref `[5ee...]` suggests that folder is referencing a different (older?) git commit. I'd suggest start by looking at your git log, git status and also check the folder hasn't somehow ended up in .gitignore. Also, your second screenshot of "frontend" - what is this? Is this your github repo?

Comment: It is a folder in my explorer, and it is a file in my bitbucket repo.
But I tried to restart the push from scratch and I deleted all old git settings. How come it conflicts with something new?

Comment: Is that folder itself a git repo ? It could have been committed as a submodule. Can you paste the output of `git ls-tree` in a terminal ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That icon, and the hash ID next to it, imply that what you have is not a file at all.  (And, Git doesn't *store* folders, so it's not a folder either.)  What it is, is what Git calls a *gitlink*.  A gitlink is the internal piece of a submodule that tells the superproject which *commit* to get out of the submodule.

A submodule is itself just another Git repository.  That means that after cloning the superproject, you must `git clone` the submodule repository as well.  The instructions that let Git do this on its own are stored in a committed file named `.gitmodules`.  If the `.gitmodules` file is missing—as appears to be the case from your screenshots, if they're complete—then Git itself can't `git clone` the submodule for you.  I like to call this a broken submodule, or sometimes a *half-assed* submodule.  To fix it, you must supply the other half of the ass: clone the appropriate Git repository.  (Then put the instructions into a `.gitmodules` file, too, so that it's fully-assed next time.)

If you don't want a submodule, don't use a gitlink.  To make Git not use a gitlink, make sure that you're not trying to add a repository to a repository: Git literally *can't* do that, so it makes a gitlink instead.