# Upload part of a project copied using git clone

Tags: git, gitlab

Apologies, the answer to this is definitely online somewhere but I had trouble distilling key terms to google! I have a git project consisting of several projects I cloned (just git clone ssh) from another user, then edited and added my own packages to.

When I try to push them to my repository though, the cloned packages show up as links to the repo I cloned from. At least, it's the symbol that normally means it's a linked package; in this case  you can't actually click on it. I want the copy with my changes to be uploaded, without having to submit a merge request or anything first.

Do I need to fork the original repos to fix this? Even though I have all the code downloaded locally, in the repo I'm trying to push from?

Edit: None of the submodules I'm trying to remove are listed in the .gitmodules, but I don't know if this is since before or after I tried removing them. I want to try adding them back in manually then doing another attempt at git submodule deinit, but will this remove all local edits I made to them?

Comment: It sounds like you've built up some submodules (or, as I sometimes call them, "half-assed submodules" where the *instructions* for *getting* the submodules are missing: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65135845/1256452)). If you want to keep using them *as* submodules, *and* add commits to some of the modified repositories so that others can get those commits, you will want to fork those other repositories (and maybe eventually get the upstreams to accept your commits so that you can switch back to them and drop your own fork).

Comment: This depends on what you want: If you want it to still be a submodule, you need to either get your patch merged into the owner's repository, or fork the repository and make the submodule point to your fork instead of the original; or if you want it not to be a submodule anymore, and just upload everything to the parent project, you can use `git submodule deinit`

Comment: @LeonardoDagnino I'd like them not to be submodules, but I ran git submodule deinit, removed some useless folders, did git add --all ./ and git commit then git push, but I still have the issue where they're appearing as linked directories without the link actually functioning :( For one module I got: No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'ModuleOne', and two others that should have unlinked got no error message but also didn't fix

Comment: Whoops, deinit wasn't it, been some time since I last messed with submodules. Just posted an answer I did some tests to confirm, should work if you follow it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I got the question correctly, but I think the term yo are looking for is `git remote`.

```
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin yourRepo
```

These 2 commands will "unlink" project from its original repo and link to yours.

Comment: Unlinking all submodules and uploading them with my edits to my repo is exactly what I'd like to do! Unfortunately running these two commands still leaves me with the broken links in my repo :( Is it possible this is an issue with my level of permissions for these repos? I'm listed as a maintainer

Answer (score 0):

To remove a submodule from your tree, you can do so using `git rm`. To remove the submodule and add its files back as part of the outer repository needs some extra steps:

You should backup first (just do a `cp -r` of the outer repository if you want to be sure), to make sure you don't lose any unpushed changes!

```sh
# Move the submodule first - otherwise the directory will be deleted when you do git rm!
mv submoduleDir sobmoduleDirBak
git rm submoduleDir
mv submoduleDir2 submodileDir
# Before adding the directory back, we have to remove its .git
rm -rf submoduleDir/.git
git add submoduleDir
```